# The switch statement is not initializing the value even if the case is True?

Tags: c, if-statement, initialization, switch-statement, c11

I want this switch statement to initialize the right value to the variable option but it is not initializing therefore not allowing the if statement to work.

```
#define arti 2.05

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    float option = 0;

    while(ch = getchar())
    {
        ch = toupper(ch);

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'A':
                option = arti; //value of arti is 2.05
                break;

            case 'B':
                option = beets;
                break;

            default:
                printf("Enter a valid value.\n");
                continue;
                break;
        }

       if(option == arti)
        {
            printf("arti printed successfully!\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output i am getting is this:

```
a //input
Enter a valid value. //output
```

I don't know where is the problem i have made this code as short as possible to explain you the problem. Please help me with this.

Comment: @AdrianMole I even tried 'A'  as input still not working.

Comment: `continue; break;` Hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a `float` value (`option`) to a `double` constant (`arti`), which is causing a problem. To define `arti` as a (single-precision) `float`, add the `f` suffix:

```c
#define arti 2.05f
```

Comment: Yo its working.....Until now i did'nt knew about it....thanks...